# Custom image filter through a HTML form and an API

Tags: javascript, php, image, forms, blogger

I would like to create a page on my blogger web where users could upload their photos and get their image with a custom filter that I define, just like Facebook did with the rainbow filter. Basically, it is a custom layer like the ones created in Photoshop, which is applied to the picture.

I've been looking for a photo editing service that can do this and provide a public API so I can call it from PHP or Javascript. So far, I have just found [Pixlr](https://pixlr.com/), but it doesn't appear to allow me to do something like this.

If anyone could guide me in the right direction, it would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up your own using OpenCV or something similar. It's not hard to learn. [OpenCV home page](http://opencv.org/)